# Neo4J - Count occurence of certain nodes in subtree

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was wondering about how to query for the occurence of certain nodes in subtrees, grouped by the parent of each subtree.

As follows:

```
I -> B -> a
       -> b
       -> b
       -> c

  -> C -> a
       -> a

  -> D -> c
```

I would like to count how many times a occurs per each subtree. In this case would result in

```
B: 1
C: 2
D: 0
```

I have been experimenting with this for a while now, but don't really have an idea how to progress since I'm new to Neo4J

Comment: Please share example of how you usually query the subtrees or share example data at http://console.neo4j.org. Not knowing how you bind any of the nodes it's hard to suggest an actual query; `MATCH (I)-->(X)-->(a {uid:"a"}) RETURN X.uid, count(a)` is the best I can come up with.

Comment: Probably use a varlength path for the subtree @jjaderberg?